# Need an example on Embedded kafka with camel

Tags: spring, junit, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I am facing issue while testing kafka with camel. I used Embedded kafka with camel and here's what I tried

I have tried this example which tells us about testing kafka using embedded kafka
https://codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-embedded-unit-test-example.html

```
package com.codenotfound.kafka.producer;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.kafka.test.assertj.KafkaConditions.key;
import static org.springframework.kafka.test.hamcrest.KafkaMatchers.hasValue;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.EmbeddedKafkaRule;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
public class SpringKafkaSenderTest {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringKafkaSenderTest.class);
private static String SENDER_TOPIC = "sender.t";

@Autowired
private Sender sender;

private KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container;

private BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records;
Object groupId;
Object bootstrapServers;

@ClassRule
public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, SENDER_TOPIC);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // set up the Kafka consumer properties
    Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("sender", "false",
            embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka());
    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : consumerProperties.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
        if (entry.getKey().equals("group.id")) {
            groupId = entry.getValue();
        } else if (entry.getKey().equals("bootstrap.servers")) {
            bootstrapServers = entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    // create a Kafka consumer factory
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(
            consumerProperties);

    // set the topic that needs to be consumed
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(SENDER_TOPIC);

    // create a Kafka MessageListenerContainer
    container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, containerProperties);

    // create a thread safe queue to store the received message
    records = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    // setup a Kafka message listener
    container.setupMessageListener(new MessageListener<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
            LOGGER.debug("test-listener received message='{}'", record.toString());
            records.add(record);
        }
    });

    // start the container and underlying message listener
    container.start();

    // wait until the container has the required number of assigned partitions
    ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getPartitionsPerTopic());
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    // stop the container
    container.stop();
}


@Test
public void testCamelWithKafka() throws Exception {
    String topicName = "topic=javainuse-topic";
    String kafkaServer = "kafka:localhost:9092";
    String zooKeeperHost = "zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181";
    String serializerClass = "serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder";

    String toKafka = new StringBuilder().append(kafkaServer).append("?").append(topicName).append("&")
            .append(zooKeeperHost).append("&").append(serializerClass).toString();
    String embedded = new StringBuilder().append(bootstrapServers).append("?").append(topicName).append("&")
            // .append(embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getZookeeperConnectionString())
            .append(zooKeeperHost).append("&").append(serializerClass).toString();
    Main main = new Main();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:D://inbox//?noop=true").split().tokenize("\n").to("direct:embedded");

        }
    });
    main.run();
  ConsumerRecord<String, String> received =
            records.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // assertThat(received, hasValue(greeting));
    // AssertJ Condition to check the key
    // assertThat(received).has(key(null));
    // System.out.println(received);
}
```

}

Camel should able to read from a file and move the data to kafka and consumer should able to read it.

Comment: Provide one example on "Camel should able to read form embedded kafka queue"

Comment: I am also looking for similar example!. I can't get the camel-kafka producer to connect to embedded kafka and send messages!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Runwith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)` to run the test case.